# SSRS 2008 R2, Farm - Load Balanced and HTTP status 401: Unauthorized

Tags: security, powershell, reporting-services, load-balancing, server-farm

I have SQL Server Reporting services 2008 R2 environment in my Company.

2 servers Windows 2008 R2: **PRERPSW01 and PRERPSW02**, in domain *DOMAIN_Company*
NLB name: **PRERPS**

IPs address ( I get by ping command):

```
PRERPSW01   192.168.110.41
prerps      192.168.90.92
```

hosts file in PRERPSW01 server

```
192.168.110.41  prerps
```

In **PRERPSW01 and PRERPSW02** servers, there is this configuration:

```
Config Report Server: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.REPORTING\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config
HostName: PRERPS. 
UrlRoot: http://PRERPS/ReportServer
```

In **PRERPSW01**, I use credentials `PRERPSW01\installerUser`

Open IE with `http://PRERPS/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx` and I cannot access

Open IE with `http://PRERPSW01/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx` and I can access

I have Poweshell script to deploy RDL files using URI `http://PRERPS/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx`

But I get the error

***The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized***.

In my PC, with credentials **DOMAIN_Company\My_user**,

Open IE with http://PRECASRPS/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx and I CAN access

Any suggestions?

**Updated**

Now, I use credentials `DOMAIN_Company\PreRPSAdministrator`.
The same configuration for rsreportserver.config.

Test in **PRERPSW01** is OK
Test in **PRERPSW02** is *KO*

Log _ReportServerService__09_22_2015_13_58_31.log_ for **PRERPSW02** test:

```
library!WindowsService_0!9cc!09/22/2015-14:38:48:: i INFO: Call to CleanBatch()
library!WindowsService_0!9cc!09/22/2015-14:38:48:: i INFO: Cleaned 0 batch records, 0 policies, 0 sessions, 0 cache entries, 0 snapshots, 0 chunks, 0 running jobs, 0 persisted streams, 0 segments, 0 segment mappings, 0 edit sessions.
library!WindowsService_0!9cc!09/22/2015-14:38:48:: i INFO: Call to CleanBatch() ends
ui!ReportManager_0-1!fa8!09/22/2015-14:39:44:: e ERROR: System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SetConnectionProtocol()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod(Boolean setConnectionProtocol)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.ListItemTypes()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.Global.SecureAllAPI()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.GlobalLinks.Control_Init(Object sender, EventArgs args)
ui!ReportManager_0-1!fa8!09/22/2015-14:39:44:: e ERROR: HTTP status code --> 500
-------Details--------
System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SetConnectionProtocol()

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod(Boolean setConnectionProtocol)

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod()

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.ListItemTypes()

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.Global.SecureAllAPI()

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.EnsureHttpsLevel()

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.ReportingPage_Init(Object sender, EventArgs args)

   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
ui!ReportManager_0-1!e70!09/22/2015-14:39:50:: e ERROR: System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SetConnectionProtocol()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod(Boolean setConnectionProtocol)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.ListItemTypes()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.Global.SecureAllAPI()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.EnsureHttpsLevel()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.ReportingPage_Init(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
ui!ReportManager_0-1!c4c!09/22/2015-14:39:51:: e ERROR: System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SetConnectionProtocol()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod(Boolean setConnectionProtocol)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.ListItemTypes()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.Global.SecureAllAPI()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.EnsureHttpsLevel()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.ReportingPage_Init(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Answer (score 3):

Local accounts + NLB = predictable failure. 
Either use the domain account to access the virtual server name, or if you're going to run tasks on the local boxes with local accounts, then configure a hosts entry so the virtual server name uses the local machine exclusively.  NLBs often cache routes by IP address (not pure round robin balancing) which can lead to 'but the local account works sometimes' scenario.  But if you're routed to the other nodes in the NLB the local account will fail.

Comment: I agree with this, when you see the dreaded "The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized." you are having authentication issues. I would go with a domain account.

Comment: Now, I use credentials **DOMAIN_Company\PreRPSAdministrator**, and I get the same error for PRERPSW02 node. For PRERPSW01 node is OK.

Comment: on both servers set the following host file entry: PRERPSW02 128.0.0.1 PRERPSW01 128.0.0.1 see if that fixes it.  also please review this blog post since you might need to disable loop back prevention http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukaszp/archive/2008/07/18/reporting-services-http-401-unauthorized-host-headers-require-your-attention.aspx